# how to parse json as a raw string in bigquery

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I have a json string that I want to parse as a raw string to get the whole value of the "age"

```
select JSON_VALUE(data,'$.age') from (
select '{"name": "Jakob", "age": "\"6\"" }' as data
) a
```

Things i tried so far

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(data, '$.age') AS age
FROM (
  SELECT '{"name": "Jakob", "age":"\"6\""}' AS data
) a;
```

returns nothing

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(data, '$.age') AS age
FROM (
  SELECT '{"name": "Jakob", "age":"\"6\""}' AS data
) a;
```

returns nothing

want to get this value = ""6""

Answer (score 1):

The double quotes in the value of the '$.age' is the issue for BigQuery JSON functions, therefore, I looked to doing it in below manner. hope this helps

```
with cte as (
  select '{"name": "Jakob", "age": "\"6\"" }' as data
) select *,json_extract(replace(data,'""','"'),'$.age') as age
from cte
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer but is there any way to convert it into a raw json string .

Comment: when i use "r" infront of the string i am able to get the value .                       
 ```  SELECT JSON_VALUE(data, '$.age') AS age
FROM (
  SELECT r'{"name": "Jakob", "age":"\"6\""}' AS data
) a; ```

Comment: this also gives "6".. so if there is a way to parse the json string as a raw string

Comment: Yep, the answer from @user22520287 seems to be working

Comment: is there any other way to do it..